Eclipse maven : MAVEN_ARGS is ignored
I have MAVEN_ARGS set to -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT so that maven can connect to artifactory.
When I run maven from PowerShell, everything is fine : maven downloads every dependencies.
Unfortunately within Eclipse, it doesn't work : I get PKIX path building failed.
To avoid the problem I must first compile the project outside Eclipse to download the dependencies.
How can I make Eclipse see MAVEN_ARGS ?

What have you tried so far to set those args?

I took a look at "Window -> Preferences -> Maven" but I couldn't find a way to set my user property for every project. A workaround to this problem is to launch mvn eclipse:eclipse from the command line.

You have to set the MAVEN_ARGS environment variable in the Maven launch configuration. Environment variables set outside of Eclipse are not visible in a launch configuration. Alternatively, use a .mvn/maven.config file if it should be project specific (see e.g. here for an example).

Do not use eclipse:eclipse anymore it's a long time end-of-life (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) Which version of Eclipse do you use?

I use Eclipse 2024-09 (4.33.0)

Adding .mvn/maven.config doesn't help

Executing mvn dependency:resolve and mvn dependency:resolve-plugins is another way to solve this problem
